# WCF как узнать Ip подключенного/отключенного клиента?

Tags: c#, wcf

Здравствуйте.
Необходимо на стороне WCF хоста иметь событие подключения/отключения клиента.
Отключение в данном случае возникает после истечения времени жизни сессии.

Каждого клиента я должен опознать (Ip адрес или специфическая информация указанная в настройках клиента не важно, главное опознать)).
 Я использую пере определение поведения конечной точки.

```
    class ClientTrackerEndpointBehavior : IEndpointBehavior
{
    public void AddBindingParameters(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
    {
    }

    public void ApplyClientBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, ClientRuntime clientRuntime)
    {
    }

    public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, EndpointDispatcher endpointDispatcher)
    {
        // подключаем наш класс 
        endpointDispatcher.ChannelDispatcher.ChannelInitializers.Add(new ClientTrackerChannelInitializer());
    }

    public void Validate(ServiceEndpoint endpoint)
    {
    }
}
```

> ClientTrackerChannelInitializer

```
class ClientTrackerChannelInitializer : IChannelInitializer
{
    internal static int ConnectedClientCount = 0;
    public static ISubject<ClientConnectionInfo> ClientConnectChange { get; } = new Subject<ClientConnectionInfo>();

    // метод, который определяет, что клиент подсоединился, создался новый канал
    public void Initialize(IClientChannel channel) //!!!!!!!хотелось бы тут видеть инфу про клинта
    {
        ConnectedClientCount++;
        Console.WriteLine("Client {0} initialized", channel.SessionId);
        channel.Closed += ClientDisconnected;
        channel.Faulted += ClientDisconnected;

        ClientConnectChange.OnNext(new ClientConnectionInfo { Action = channel.State, SessionId = channel.SessionId, IpAdress = channel.LocalAddress.ToString()});
    }
    // событие, на которое подписались при создании канала
    static void ClientDisconnected(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var channel = (IClientChannel) sender;
        ConnectedClientCount--;
        ClientConnectChange.OnNext(new ClientConnectionInfo { Action = channel.State, SessionId = channel.SessionId, IpAdress = channel.LocalAddress.ToString() });
    }
}
```

> запуск хоста

```
                    string baseAddress = "http://192.168.1.33:4000/Service";
                service = new ServiceHost(typeof(Service), new Uri(baseAddress));

                //MEX EndPoint
                ServiceMetadataBehavior smb = service.Description.Behaviors.Find<ServiceMetadataBehavior>();
                if (smb == null)
                    smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
                smb.HttpGetEnabled = true;
                smb.MetadataExporter.PolicyVersion = PolicyVersion.Policy15;
                service.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);
                service.AddServiceEndpoint( ServiceMetadataBehavior.MexContractName,   MetadataExchangeBindings.CreateMexHttpBinding(),"mex");

                //IContract EndPoint
                WSHttpBinding binding = new WSHttpBinding(SecurityMode.None, true);
                binding.OpenTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 20);
                binding.CloseTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 20);
                binding.SendTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 5);       //таймаут на Запрос-ответ
                binding.ReceiveTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 25);   //время жизни сесии (при бездействии клиентов)
                ServiceEndpoint endpoint = service.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IContract), binding, "");
                endpoint.Behaviors.Add(new ClientTrackerEndpointBehavior());

                service.Open();
```

События Initialize и ClientDisconnected срабатывают исправно. Но вот никакой информации о клиенте я узнать из них не могу 
channel.RemoteAddress == null

подскажите может надо как то настроить клиента, чтобы он передавал Ip. Но только не в методе контракта))), тогда я получу подключившегося клиента и его Ip, но вот отключение его я не прослежу.

Заранее всем спасибо!!

Answer (score 1):

текущий IP клиента я получаю так

```
private static string _getClientIP(OperationContext context)
{
    MessageProperties prop = context.IncomingMessageProperties;
    RemoteEndpointMessageProperty endpoint =
        prop[RemoteEndpointMessageProperty.Name] as RemoteEndpointMessageProperty;
    return endpoint.Address;
}
```

К сожалению, не помню уже где подсмотрел это решение, по этому просто (с)перто.
Работает даже если у клиента во время одной сессии меняется IP, актуально для мобильных клиентов. Не нужно ни контрактов. ни переопределений endpoint.

---

Текущий контекст можно получить так:

```
var context = OperationContext.Current;
```

Comment: я видел такой код). а как вызывать я не понял, откуда брать context?

Comment: @Aldmi добавил как получить текущий контекст

Comment: внутри Initialize метода OperationContext.Current == null. Внутри метода сервиса, да это работает, но мне нужен Ip именно подключенного и отключенного клиента.

Comment: например у меня 2 клиента как мне узнать кто из них подключен?

Comment: можно использовать стандартный вариант подписки. Статический лист клиентов, в который по методу Connect клиент добавляется, по методу Disconnect удаляется. Я этот прием использую при DualBinding, где какбе нужно знать своих клиентов не только по IP но и по колбекам

Comment: метод Connect  и  Disconnect  они где находятся?

Comment: обычные методы контракта сервиса, назвать можете как угодно

Comment: ладно предположим, Connect я отловлю и помещю ip в список.  как отловить Disconnect? Клиент отвалился сессия живет например 10 мин и через 10 минут я должен знать что клиент отвалился

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48065/discussion-between-rdorn-and-aldmi).